# Fluid domain not baking

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am new to blender and was taking this tut from:

- [Blender Tutorial - Realistic Fluid Simulation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmw-BTCbWMw)

to create a sim of fluid. However, the domain remains as it is and
   does not bake at all. Here's the

- [Blend File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TAcrjBVVwATa0QqvWaaufsEzymzmWEAW).

I have tried every solution from the internet I could find and yet it's unsolved.

Comment: One example of such a try perhaps?

Comment: what Anam Shahid said is right. Also try applying scale and location to all your objects involved. And make sure you have an empty directory set, as well as saving before you can bake.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have checked your file.. you can try doing what i did

1. I extruded the circle a bit and gave it a little volume..
2. try changing inflow velocity on x axis to 0.1m/s

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all these solutions but I just found out that there were two versions of blender 2.8(old beta) and 2.8(new one) causing the process to not work. It worked after I deleted the old one.

Comment: Really? It wasn't baking on my latest stable version 2.8 until I changed these properties.

Answer (score 0):

try making these changes and that will work

[image]